# How to correct a link... Or is it a GNOME Desktop menu entry?

Tags: gnome, symlink, ln

Few days ago, I've downloaded *IntelliJ* in my `Downloads` folder.

I've executed `bin/idea.sh` installed it, and a convenient icon became available in my GNOME Desktop named *IntelliJ*, and was shown whenever I hit **I** letter, to help launching it.

Then, this morning I destroyed the folder of *IntelliJ* in my *Downloads* directory, believing it was only used for setup and that the real software had been installed elsewhere (`/opt/...`, `/usr/local/...`). But it wasn't the case. Considering my mistake I had to re-download it, reinstall it, elsewhere, with it's `bin/idea.sh` script.

It works fine again.
Except... that I have no more the *IntelliJ* icon that comes when I type the first letter **i** in GNOME Desktop.

I guess a link is still somewhere, leading to the previous location ?
Or is it something different, related to GNOME specifically, that I have to search for and edit ?

1. What can I check to correct this ?
2. By the way, is there a `ln` option that list all the links available on the system ?
3. and checks if they are still accurate ?

Comment: Try `find $HOME -name "*.desktop"` and see if anything related to IntelliJ comes up.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thanks ! It worked well !

Answer (score 0):

For all other possible users encountering something similar, JetBrains products have an option to create a desktop launcher of an application for a single user or system-wide. This option is optional and is not a part of the installation. Created deskop launchers can be found in `~/.local/share/applications` for a single user and `/usr/share/applications` for system-wide.

You can modify `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` as you like, but you should not touch files in `/usr/share/applications`, because these files are usually created by your package manager and will be overwritten or removed when you update or remove related package.